# View list of teasers wrapped in <li> instead of <div>

Tags: 7, theming

How can I view my teasers in `<li>` instead of in the default `<div>`? I find that changing the `<div>` to `<li>` in `node.tpl.php` doesn't work since `<li>` needs to be wrapped in a `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree you should use Views for this. You can replicate Drupal's default front page, just by enabling the default front page view that comes with views. You can use the regular View style plugins to create lists, tables, etc. Using things like [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) in Drupal 6 and by configuring the styles in Views 3 you can have clean markup and have more exotic things like definition lists.

To understand how Views outputs its markup you should have a look at the templates views comes with in the themes folder, if you want to see how views outputs lists for example check out views-view-list.tpl.php.

Comment: Got it right the first time. I was just feeling lazy and thought there was a way to just edit the node.tpl.php. Thanks for reinforcing the thought! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to output an unordered list of teasers. You can use the **HTML List** display type, along with a **Node: Teaser** field.